Why would an incumbent politician or party need to be re-elected to fulfill a campaign promise?
Back in July when he was still running for President, Joe Biden made the following promise:

I banned assault weapons once.
When I’m re-elected, I’m going to do it again.

But... Biden is already the sitting President! If there's an executive order he could sign to ban assault weapons, he could do it tomorrow and not wait for January 20th, 2025. Similarly the Conservative party in the UK made the following promise during the 2019 election, despite the fact that they could've just passed such a law effective immediately instead:

We will introduce tougher
sentencing for the worst offenders
and end automatic halfway release
from prison for serious crimes. For
child murderers, there will be life
imprisonment without parole.

Incumbent politicians make statements like this all the time but it seems like they're almost never challenged on this. Why is that the case?

Note: this question isn't about assault weapons or the wisdom of tough sentencing laws. I've just used them as examples of very specific promises made by incumbent politicians.


The most obvious obstacle to the US President getting their agenda passed into legislation, is that their party doesn't have a majority in both the House of Representatives and the Senate, which very commonly happens after midterm elections. This kind of promise is made in a presidential campaign, but they are also campaigning for people to vote for their own party's candidates in the House and the Senate during the same elections.

For the UK example, the situation is quite different because the Prime Minister necessarily has support of a majority of Parliament. However, it may be that their party's MPs don't all agree on the policy idea, so they wouldn't be able to pass it; but if they promised it in their manifesto and won re-election, the holdouts from their own party would have a harder time justifying their lack of support for that policy.

IIRC, Trump similarly keeps promising he'll eliminate citizenship for 'anchor babies', and Trump was even explicit he'll do it by executive order. But was he ever challenged why didn't he do it last time, esp by exec order?

Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/what-does-the-potus-do-exactly

If POTUS do everything during sitting there will be no need in the next term at all. A carrot must be always in front of a donkey.

There are all kinds of real and imagined reasons why things may be possible tomorrow that are not possible today, but I fear that at the end of the day the true answer to your question is "because we got used to it". It happens everywhere, it rarely makes sense, and it's just accepted as part of the game. Sigh.

Trump does it, but he certainly did not invent this specific abomination of an argument. Here in Austria, one political party has held the finance ministry for decades, and they still promise a tax reform ever. single. election. It usually does not happen, if it happens it's much smaller in scope than promised, and if somebody calls them out it's somebody else's fault why it could not be done. And then they promise it again with a completely straight face.

@timetakesitstoll In that case it would take a lot more than just a vote by Congress: in the US birthright citizenship is in the Constitution.

Remember that campaign promises are promises to try. Success depends on a lot of factors, including whether the other party cares more about their own success or about their opponents failure.

The first time, in 1994, it was not simply an Executive Order, but rather a law passed by Congress, a subset of the "Violent Crime Control and Law Enforcement Act"
Biden was a member of Congress at the time, so his vote counted. He did not do it all by himself.
But further, then-Sen Biden drafted the Senate version of this. While it did take House of Reps and Senate to pass this, Biden was instrumental in its passing.
So "I did it before" is not entirely misleading.
Similarly, it would take an act of Congress to get it done again.
Biden thinks (thought) he could get enough impetus to get Congress to do it again.

From what I can tell, it's pretty common for POTUS candidates in general to make campaign promises that they themselves couldn't single-handedly deliver even if elected, i.e. implicitly promising they''ll get Congress to agree. Something which is far less of a given in the US than in the UK, although MP 'rebellions' happen there too sometimes.

I had been wondering why Trump keeps saying he'll remove citizenship from 'anchor babies' by exec order, but why he didn't do it last time. I guess the argument is somewhat similar that he expected courts' opposition, but the SCOTUS will be 'fixed so good' in his 2nd term that that won't be an issue anymore.

@timetakesitstoll: Even in its current state, I don't think the Supreme Court has five votes to overturn Wong Kim Ark.

@Kevin: apparently their argument is that Wong Kim Ark doesn't apply to children of illegal aliens, but apparently weren't willing to try that in a court yet https://www.factcheck.org/2023/06/trumps-dubious-promise-to-end-birthright-citizenship/ N.B. there's also Plyler v. Doe that's apparently relevant on that angle, and that one was 5-4 in 1982.

@timetakesitstoll POTUS has very little power to make changes by themselves, almost anything of signififance requires congressional action. So campaign promises are about their agenda, not things they'll do single-handedly.

@timetakesitstoll: I'm very skeptical. That would require a highly nonstandard definition of the word "jurisdiction." The usual definition is that a person is within the "jurisdiction" of a country if the country can enforce all of its laws against them. A criminal at large is within the jurisdiction of the country, because the country may at any time arrest them. A diplomat or consular official is not within the jurisdiction of the host country under the Vienna Convention. A member of an invading force is (arguably) exempt under the Geneva Convention. An illegal alien has no such immunity.

@Kevin I don't see "jurisdiction" in any previous comment, what are you responding to? Has it since been deleted?

@Barmar: The word "jurisdiction" appears in the 14th Amendment to the United States Constitution, and was the individual word at issue in Wong Kim Ark. Overturning Wong Kim Ark would require interpreting that word differently, because that's what the case was all about in the first place.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever I suspect Plyler would be overruled by the current court as it appears to be a weird exception to other precedents; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspect_classification#Alienage

Doing things in government takes time.  If you have 10 big things to do, you have to prioritize, and maybe only get 3 of them done per year.
The reason why things take time varies.  In the US President's case, the US President has very roughly the legislative power of 1/3 of the US congress and 1/3 of the US Senate; this isn't absolute.  So getting something done legislatively requires cooperation of a good chunk of both.
Sometimes that cooperation comes in the form of deals.  You agree to do X, and they pass Y; such deals can include legislative blackmail, like including some change in a bill whose failure to pass results in harm to something the other side really wants.
US Presidents also have the ability to talk about things and be listened to; but again, this power is limited.  This lets them decide what is important to their agenda, and sway political winds in order to get marginal opponents to become marginal supporters in order for they themselves to stay elected.
In the UK case, drafting such a law and getting it passed through parliament is a large endevour if you don't want to make a bad job of it.  While the headline might read "increase the punishment for crime X", the actual law would probably cover dozens of different illegal activities.  You'd want to ensure that sentencing guidelines are effectively changed, that the law itself remains constitutional, and that you don't result in stupid errors in your laws like "you just made biting someone's hand aggressively a 25 year sentence, while cutting it off is only a 5 year sentence".
In practice, this would involve both political workers (who work for the conservative party) working out a draft of what is needed, it going through the civil service (where there is lots of expertise) going over it again, then bringing the bill to the floor.  There it would be read and debated by the members of parliament, amended or not, then if passed go to the upper house.  There it again would be debated and amended, and if amended sent back to the lower house.
All of this takes time to do properly.
What is worse is that is you are half way through this process (in the voting part) and an election occurs, the earlier votes and steps are thrown out.
So starting such a process now, close to an election, is probably going to result in the law not being passed prior to the election (unless they push it through with unseemly haste, which tends to result in bad laws).
In addition, in both the UK and in the USA, parties aren't monoliths either.  By having a policy be a plank of the party on an election cycle you are more likely to get legislators in the party to work to get the policy implemented.

This is the proper answer: 4 years is a relatively short time in national politics. It's a bit as if you had a month to repair and renovate the house you live in. You will get a few things done but you'd almost certainly want another one, and another one after that, if you can have it.

Simply because an executive order can be removed by the next president that takes the office. Even if Biden does an executive order and it isn't blocked/overturned by the courts if Trump wins the election he will simply remove it.
Biden Repealing 5 Trump Executive Orders Marks New Day of Hope for Feds

Biden revoked three executive orders issued by the Trump
administration that attempted to eliminate collective bargaining, due
process, and workplace representation rights for federal employees.
He repealed Trump’s Schedule F executive order which permitted the
Trump administration to hire and fire federal employees for political
reasons.
He also reversed Trump’s ban on the use of federal funds
for diversity and inclusion training programs for federal employees
and the employees of federal contractors.


It’s definitely a good point but… it seems weird that he wouldn’t do it immediately anyway? Why wait 6 months, just do it straight away and hope you win.

@JonathanReez You seem to be missing the point, doing it as an executive order is pretty much meaningless. The purpose of promising to do it after the election is with the intention that they will be able to get it passed as a law instead which will have more power overall.

I now realize I should’ve found examples from George W Bush’s second campaign when he had a Republican trifecta and therefore no excuse to not execute his promise on the spot. But I think the UK example is valid.

@JoeW You're absolutely correct about the temporariness of executive orders (although their effects can last for a long time even after the order is revoked).  But it'd still be weird to promise to issue an executive order again if you kept the office.  Normally, they'd say something like "I'll keep this ban/policy in place".

@Bobson That is assuming that the action isn't prevented by the courts as there are plenty of things that would get overtured as an executive order.

I doubt it could be done as an executive order at all. A Trump administration regulation banning bump stocks was struck down by SCOTUS and that was more than a mere executive order.

A democratic government is not supposed to be a "temporary dictatorship". They are supposed to describe in general terms what their plans are, get elected, implement those plans.
In general they can behave as temporary dictators and changing circumstances can reasonably justify a change of plan but most democratic governments at least try to look like they are not going too far from their manifestos for major changes. Going to the polls early to gain a mandate for a major change is not unheard of.
Interestingly this is codified in the UK system (as much as anything in the UK is codified) in that the house of Lords is not supposed to frustrate the government's policies if those policies were in the manifesto, but can resist them to a much greater amount if they weren't

Something the other answers miss, and is not necessarily about the current situation, but a sitting POTUS may be facing a Congress where the opposing party is either in partial or full control, either the House or Senate or both are the opposing party. This may mean that trying to get a bill through that's polarized by party would meet significant resistance, or come to a full stop even before it's even fully considered.
Knowing that a bill likely wouldn't pass, POTUS may be expecting the power within Congress to shift more to their favor after the election, where their party either takes control or there are simply more of their party in the Minority. It may also be that certain people in Congress are expected to retire who are "hardliners" that have no chance of being negotiated with, and expecting that whomever is elected will be more open to voting with POTUS, even if they aren't the same party.
For example:
Let's say that Mary is very much against the topic POTUS is campaigning about, but she is expecting to retire and let someone else take over. Or her term is up and a rival is expected to take the election.
Jake is then elected and is the same party as Mary, but not the same as POTUS. Jake has no strong ties to the party and shows that he is either for the topic or maybe simply can be convinced to vote for the bill. This makes it more likely the bill can pass in the new Congress.
Or maybe Mary is replace with Jasmine, who is the same party as POTUS, so can almost be guaranteed to vote with the party and POTUS on the topic.
So, using this example, if several hardliner Marys are replaced with a couple of Jakes and Jasmines, there's a higher chance of the bill passing through Congress. And it's not just that the hardliners aren't there to vote, but they also aren't there to pressure others into voting against the bill.

In Australia there is a combination of a Westminster system, where the party that controls the House of Representatives gets to choose the Prime Minister and Cabinet, with a Senate; usually the Government does not have a majority in the Senate.
There is a convention that the Senate will not block legislation if the government has "a mandate". This is a somewhat loose term, but is usually taken to include campaign promises. It is backed up by a constitutional mechanism, double dissolution, which allows the Government to appeal the the voters; this is seldom used, but it makes a credible threat.

Many promises are simply not possible because without enough support in (congress, or whatever body).
The best example would be (socialized / single payer / Medicare for all) health care. For years these have been a long-term goal of the political left in the US. Each election cycle we get a little closer to this happening.
For the politicians promoting this they “need reelected to accomplish the goal” for those opposed “need reelected to stop creeping socialism”.

"Many promises are simply not possible because without enough support in (congress, or whatever body)" - can you elaborate on this? Why might the incumbent party need "more support" to be able to enact their policies? What would constitute "more support" exactly?

Many (but not most) members of congress are not in the majority party, however beyond that not all items are passed on a straight party line vote.  The best example of this is how often people voted with/against the president.  Even with the most polarizing president it was common for members of congress not to vote with there party leadership.   While this bipartisanship can be praise by the voters at large, it often annoys the party leadership (and donors)
https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/congress-trump-score/house/
